# How to mailing a file from %appdata%

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have this codes:

```
void SendMail()
{
    epost.From = new MailAddress("mymailtest@gmail.com");
    epost.To.Add(textBoxMail.Text.ToString());
    epost.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text.ToString();
    epost.Body = textBoxBody.Text.ToString(); //Idk how to change it to my path help pls.

    SmtpClient smpt = new SmtpClient();

    smpt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymailtest@gmail.com", "123456789loll.");
    smpt.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smpt.EnableSsl = true;
    smpt.Port = 587;

    smpt.Send(epost);
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");

}
```

I want change here to my path.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
using System.IO;
```

```
static public string CreateSpecialFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder folder,
                                             string company,
                                             string application)
{
  string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(folder), company, application);
  Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
  return path;
}
```

You can write such thing for example:

```
string folder = CreateSpecialFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData,
                                        "MyCompany",
                                        "MyApp");
epost.Body = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(folder, textBoxBody.Text));
```

Comment: Thanks for help <3. I put "test.txt" to filename and I got this error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ''C:\Users\Raşit\source\repos\Program\Program\bin\Debug\Test.txt' file not found.'

Comment: You need to have an existing file to read it and put it in the body property... else you need to create it before.